# get() always return null in Room database test

Tags: database, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to android and database, and studying Room Database from Google website. When I try to test the the methods in SleepDataBaseDao, sleepDao.get() always returns null. Here is the code. The insertAndGetNight() passes, but testGet() fails. I have no idea why this happens.

```
    @Test
        @Throws(Exception::class)
        fun insertAndGetNight() {
            val night = SleepNight()
            sleepDao.insert(night)
            val tonight = sleepDao.getTonight()
            assertEquals(tonight?.sleepQuality, -1)
        }
    @Test
        @Throws(Exception::class)
        fun testGet() {
            val night : SleepNight = SleepNight()
            val nightID : Long = night.nightId
            sleepDao.insert(night)
            val finalNight = sleepDao.get(nightID)
            assertEquals(finalNight?.nightId, nightID)
        }
```

```
    @Dao
    interface SleepDatabaseDao {
        @Insert
        fun insert(night: SleepNight)
    
        @Update
        fun update(night: SleepNight)
    
        @Query("SELECT * FROM daily_sleep_quality_table WHERE nightId=:key")
        fun get(key: Long): SleepNight
    
        @Query("DELETE FROM daily_sleep_quality_table")
        fun clear()
    
        @Query("SELECT * FROM daily_sleep_quality_table ORDER BY nightId DESC LIMIT 1")
        fun getTonight(): SleepNight?
    
        @Query("SELECT * FROM daily_sleep_quality_table ORDER BY nightId DESC")
        fun getAllNights():LiveData<List<SleepNight>>
    }
```

```
    @Entity(tableName = "daily_sleep_quality_table")
    data class SleepNight(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var nightId: Long = 0L,
    
        @ColumnInfo(name = "start_time_milli")
        var startTimeMilli: Long = System.currentTimeMillis(),
    
        @ColumnInfo(name = "end_time_milli")
        var endTimeMilli: Long = startTimeMilli,
    
        @ColumnInfo(name = "quality_rating")
        var sleepQuality: Int = -1
    )
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: please do not share photos of the code rather copy and paste your code here, as it makes it easier for another person to copy and paste and help you out easily. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15097422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have default id 0 in your SleepNight class but autoGenerate is true. I think that when you are creating new SleepNight your nightID is 0, but ids in database table starting from 1 and dao cant find it.

Comment: I changed the default id to 1 and it does work now. Thank you! I thought default id is just useless and the real id will be the generated one, but I don't know its id is still 0, I am confused about the function of autoGenerate now. I will try to search more about it.